# Redirect messages directed at the GPU

Tags: c, linux, gpu

Is there anything as low level as that on any Linux distribution? My overall goal is to redirect the message (instruction) meant for the GPU.
That means I would have to be able to program a driver between the CPU and the GPU which redirects any message to where I'd like (like a packet sniffer, but for GPU instructions and one that would stop the info there).

Is there any native Linux support for this kind of thing? Where do I start and what OS is most recommended for this kind of access?

Comment: If you are using something such as OpenGL, you might want to consider debug tools: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Debugging_Tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to modify the GPU driver.  There you can insert logging or whatever other redirection you have in mind.  Since many graphics drivers on Linux are open-source, this should be possible for many graphics cards.  But take note that it won't be portable--you'll need to write some separate code for each major variant of GPU you want to support.

If you have something more specific, like that you're trying to capture OpenGL commands, that might make things easier.

Comment: Is there a Linux distribution where you can do this? (One where I don't need to modify this, say one where you have a function pointer you can modify through a certain call and redirect to your written function). The overall goal is to write an external graphics card (the function that would be called when 'sniffing' an instruction would transfer the instruction to my device via a usb and it will return the pixels to display, calculated in the external device). Is it possible? How hard would the work be on each end?

Comment: Is it possible?  Yes.  Is there a distribution that supports this?  Almost certainly not, because it'd be a feature of the driver, not the distribution.  How hard would the work be?  If you have to ask: very difficult.